# ActivityRecognitionApi vs ActivityRecognitionClient issue

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I have updated the google play services library to the latest version.

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">6587000</integer>
```

I am working on the User Activity Recognition. Previous Google Play service library having the class ActivityRecognitionClient. After I have changed to the latest Google play service library I found the class ActivityRecognitionApi. But There is no connect or disconnect method available for the new class.

```
/**
 * Request a connection to Location Services. This call returns immediately,
 * but the request is not complete until onConnected() or
 * onConnectionFailure() is called.
 */
private void requestConnection() {
    getActivityRecognitionClient().connect();
}
```

getActivityRecognitionClient() method is unavailable in new Google Play service library. If i use the instance of ActivityRecognitionApi class, it dont have the connect or disconnect method.

In the Android developer site also they have not updated the given tutorial to newly introduced api called ActivityRecognitionApi.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue. [This blog post will help you.](https://blacode.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/user-activity-recognition-through-new-activityrecognitionapi-in-android-activityrecognitionclient-deprecated/)

Now you have to use GoogleApiClient for user Activity Updates.

Comment: Thanks Aditya. This is what I expected. And one more question regarding this. We are not calling manually  getActivityRecognitionClient().connect() right?. The API will take care of this and we will get a onconnected callback once successfully connected Is it like this?

Comment: Yes. You can view the code screenshots at the bottom of that post :)

Comment: If you're using Google Accounts for login you can see how to use GoogleApiClient here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-google-accounts/blob/master/QuickStart/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/accounts/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java If you strictly use Google Play Location services then you can reference https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample with a small modification to the api being called and the buildGoogleApiClient method (add .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)).

Comment: Here is my blog post with sample. Try it. https://www.hrupin.com/2016/05/how-to-use-activityrecognitionapi-library-from-google